# How do I grant a specific permission to a Cloud IAM service account using the gcloud CLI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam

I know that I can do it via the UI (Cloud Console), and that I can also assign a role. Although, how do I grant a single permission easily?

For example, I was pushing an image to Google Container Registry with a newly created service account, and I got an error saying that this service account doesn't have the `storage.buckets.get` permission. What is the easiest way to grant this specific permission using the CLI?

Answer (score 36):

You can't directly grant a permission to a service account, that's simply not how Google Cloud IAM works. [Only roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) are assigned to service accounts, users or groups which in turn usually contain a set of permissions.

If you want a role to only contain a single permission, or only permissions you're interested in, you can look into [creating a custom role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#creating_a_custom_role), which allows you to specify which permission(s) you want to give to a role of your definition in order to restrict the access on a more granular level. And then, assign that custom role to the service account:

1. Using the `gcloud` CLI you can **create a custom role** with
   [`gcloud iam roles create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/roles/create), i.e:

   ```
   gcloud iam roles create bucketViewer \
       --project example-project-id-1 \
       --title "Bucket viewer" \
       --description "This role has only the storage.buckets.get permission" \
       --permissions storage.buckets.get
   ```

   This will create a custom role with the ID `bucketViewer`, for the
   project ID `example-project-id-1`, containing only the permission
   `storage.buckets.get`. Replace these values as desired and
   accordingly.
2. Once done, you can **assign this custom role** also with a single `gcloud`
   command by using [`gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding):

   ```
   gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding example-project-id-1 \
         --member='serviceAccount:test-proj1@example.domain.com' \
         --role='projects/example-project-id-1/roles/bucketViewer'
   ```

   Replace `example-project-id-1` with your project ID, and
   `test-proj1@example.domain.com` with the actual name of the service
   account you want to assign the role to.

Comment: Do you know what is the reason behind such a clunky access management approach?

Comment: maybe create custom roles looks like a unnecessary step, but if you have a lot of users is easier to set roles instead individual permissions for each user, i think that this is not fit for projects or organizations with few users, but when the project grows in the number of users this option has more sense.

Comment: Command to add binding worked without quotes for me.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely don't want to assign single permission. It usually requires more permissions to achieve what you want.

Those permissions are organized into roles - you either pick existing one, or create own, like described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59757152.

But typically there are some existing predefined roles. You need to find them in Google Cloud documentation - e.g. for container registry https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control - your choice could be Storage Object Admin (roles/storage.objectAdmin).

Those roles are actually Cloud Storage roles which are described in https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles.

Answer (score 2):

## Easily grant bucket access permission to a service account

### TL;DR

**Buckets** => **three dots menu** on the target bucket line => **Edit Access**

*... and **no**, it's not in the Service account permissions tab...*

### Step by step

1. In the Google Cloud console GUI go to the navigation menu and choose "Cloud Storage" (https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/)
2. Choose "Buckets" if not already chosen
3. Find the bucket you want to add the permission to
4. Open the "More actions"/"three dots" menu on the target bucket row
5. Choose "Edit Access" (shows an option to add new and list of existing permissions below)
6. Click "Add Principal"
7. To "New principals" field add your Service account - you can find its email ID in:
   "IAM & Admin" > "Service Accounts" > column "Email"
8. In the "Assign roles" section, click into the field "Select a role"
9. In category "Cloud storage" - choose the most appropriate role

   - for the OP's case that's most likely "Storage Object Viewer"
   - **WARNING: "Storage Object User" CAN:** "**create**, read, **update** and ***DELETE*** objects and multipart uploads in GCS"
10. Click "Save", wait for the updated finished success message and you're good to go :-)

**Final note:** Some people **get confused** and are trying to set these permissions in the Service account's permission tab - ***that is wrong*** - those are permissions to access/manage/view *the service account* **itself!** :-)

Comment: omg thanks! i fell into the trap! was looking everywhere in the service account tab.

Answer (score 1):

To assign a role that grants permissions to a service account use the following:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding \
 <your-project-name-id> \
 --member='serviceAccount:service-<1234567890>@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com' \
 --role='roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1'
```

To find the role that you need with the corresponding permissions check here: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles
The rule is: be as strict as possible and grant as little permissions as possible for security reasons.

Note: Here the service account is a Google managed service account (service accounts starting with `service-` that don't appear in the GCP IAM GUI).