# No storage.buckets.get permission after assigning BucketViewer role

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gcloud, google-iam

I need to view a gcloud bucket with my service account which has a Owner role.

I followed the advice ([How do I grant a specific permission to a Cloud IAM service account using the gcloud CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756793/how-do-i-grant-a-specific-permission-to-a-cloud-iam-service-account-using-the-gc)) on **creating a custom role** called BucketViewer, that has the **storage.buckets.get permission and assigning it to my service account** and the project.

Now, when I try to view the buckets metadata (as described here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-bucket-information#get-bucket-size-cli) :

```
gsutil ls -L -b gs://bucketname
```

It still returns the error:

```
my_service@account.com does not have storage.buckets.get access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

I am glad for any help.

Comment: Did you try to give Storage Legacy Bucket Reader (roles/storage.legacyBucketReader) to your service account https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles#legacy-roles?

Comment: On which resource did you grant the permission? On the project? of the bucket?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I just tried it via : gsutil iam ch user:my@user_name.com:storage.legacyBucketWriter gs://bucketname and got another interesting error: `my@user_name.com does not have storage.buckets.getIamPolicy access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket`  Does this mean I need to get access granted in order to change permissions as such?  PS: I noticed I am a 'user' and not a 'service account', if that changes anything..

Comment: **@guillaumeblaquiere**: I granted the permission on the project. Is there a way to specify it for the bucket? The comment I used was this one: `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding example-project-id-1 \
      --member='user:test-proj1@example.domain.com' \
      --role='projects/example-project-id-1/roles/bucketViewer'`