# `juju bootstrap google google-controller` yields a `googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.projects.get' permission`

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam, identity-management, juju

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:
https://juju.is/docs/olm/google-gce

Once at the end when trying to bootstrap, I get this:

$ juju bootstrap google google-controller
ERROR googleapi: Error 403: Required 'compute.projects.get' permission for 'projects/juju-demo-364623', forbidden

I have tried for at least 30 minutes to add more permissions in GCP, however, it doesn't change anything. I am lost. I hoped the GCP permissions to be easier to manage than AWS permissions. I realize it's as confusing as AWS IAM permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Following this guided documentation page made it:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/grant-role-console

I used the owner permission which was wider and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your answer @Guillaume Chevalier, you can also use this reference answered by @Maxim to this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59756793/how-do-i-grant-a-specific-permission-to-a-cloud-iam-service-account-using-the-gc)

It's a good reference to configure a custom role, using gcloud CLI. and also explain here step by step configuration.